# Android Wifi Hotspot turn off all the time

Tags: wi-fi, wifi-hotspot, emui

Phone: Honor 8 with EMUI 5.0.1 and Android 7.0

Each time I try to turn on my wifi hotspot, it turns off after several minutes. A notification of Android System is sending and tells me that "no device is connected. Wifi Hotspot disabled" while my laptop or other devices are still connected...

Is it possible to deactivate this setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android turns off the hotspot automatically if no device connects to it for "several minutes". Now, since you are connecting your other devices and it still turns off, it seems that the your Honor is unable to recognize the connected devices and continues to feel that no external device is connected to the network.

I'm not sure why it does that, but is definitely an issue. As for Android, there is no way to turn this setting off. It will continue to turn off hotspot if no devices are detected. You can try a "factory reset" if it is possible for you.